# Function to get specified key from /proc/cpuinfo

Tags: parsing, bash, linux, shell

On Linux, the file `/proc/cpuinfo` returns a set of key-value pairs, where the key and value are separated by a colon and each pair has its own line. It's a bit more complicated than that in reality, but for my needs that's as complicated as it needs to be. (I have only one processor core.)

My goal is to write a function in bash that takes the key for one of those items and returns the value corresponding to that key. Here's my current function:

```
function get_cpuinfo_prop () {
    TARGET_LINE=$(cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep ^$1)
    IFS=':'
    read -ra PARTS <<< "$TARGET_LINE"
    PROP_VALUE=${PARTS[1]}
    echo $PROP_VALUE
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
$(get_cpuinfo_prop 'key_name')
```

Is there a better way of doing it? How could I improve this code? Additionally, I think this might be returning extra whitespace before the actual value. How can I trim those characters off the beginning/end?

Comment: What if you have more than one processor or core, as is common these days?

Comment: On the platform that this script is running on, the values that I need are not repeated for each core (and there is only one core anyway). That's what I was trying to say with that complication note; should I add this info explicitly to the question?

Comment: I think you have a bug in here. Sometimes one key can be a subset of another key. For instance, if you are looking for the key "model" this will also find the line "model name".

Comment: To fix the issue with the key subsets, you can use  grep -e -m1 "$1\s*:" The \s means, whitespace but no characters, * means, an unlimited number, and : ends the pattern at the : in the line you are looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Useless use of cat

Grep can open files all by itself, `cat` isn't necessary in most circumstances. Also, quote everything - that's save you some debugging when you need to handle spaces in them - like for the "model name" property.

```
target_line=$(grep -m1 ^"$1" /proc/cpuinfo)
```

`-m1` to stop at the first match, so you won't get weird results when you run your script on a machine with more CPUs. That's not portable unfortunately (not in POSIX), so if you don't have that, the usual options are: pipe to `head -n 1`, use `awk` instead and exit early, `sed` and exit early. The latter two can do it all in one go too.

#### Use your shells string manipulations for simple things

Assuming you want everything after the `:`, you can simply do:

```
value="${target_line##*: }"
```

See [How do I do string manipulations in bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Removing_part_of_a_string) for more like this, or the POSIX [parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) reference.

#### `function` keyword not necessary

It's less portable and doesn't buy you anything, so just omit it. See [difference between “function foo() {}” and “foo() {}”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/73750/difference-between-function-foo-and-foo) for more details.

#### Variable names don't need to be in all caps

Personal preference of course, but especially for locals, lowercase is good - keep uppercase for globals/environment variables.

So:

```
get_cpuinfo_prop () {
  target_line=$(grep -m1 ^"$1" /proc/cpuinfo)
  echo "${target_line##*: }"
}
```